# Edit HTML files manipulating DOM in a jQuery style

Tags: c#, java, javascript, jquery, html

I have a batch of HTML files which need some editions easy to perform with jQuery (mainly selecting some nodes and changing their attributes).

My approach to achive this, has been opening them one by one in Google Chrome, excecuting the jQuery code in the console, and then copying the resulting DOM back to my HTML editor.

Since what I'm currently doing takes a lot of time, and also due to the fact that every file needs the same edition (i.e., the same jQuery/JS code will work for every HTML file), I am considering to write a script/program to do this.

Anyway, I am not completely clear of which of the following (if any of them) approaches I should take to accomplish this task.

1. **Write a JavaScript** script with jQuery using some FileSystem/File manipulation library (which one?)
2. **Write a Java or C# program** using some jQuery-based library (like [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery))
3. **Finding a plugin for some of my editors** (Aptana, Notepad++, Eclipse, etc) or a completely different editor that supports jQuery-like commands for edition (just as notepad++ regex replacement support). This would be slow with big batches, but at least it would allow me to avoid the annoying copy/paste to/from Chrome.

Is one of this approaches the *right way* to accomplish what I need? (Is there a *right way* to do this?) Which should be more straight-forward?

I think that #2 would be easier for me since I have a lot more experience in Java and C# than in JavaScript, but I think that maybe that idea would be sort of using a sledgehammer to crack a nut.

Comment: Never heard about CSQuery before, it may be handy in the future. Thanks :)

Comment: There's no right answer - but if you've already written jQuery code to do this, then using CsQuery seems like an easy approach since the code should be easy to port. I wouldn't say it's using a sledgehammer -- it's just a tool that does what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the right way but it sounds like you are familiar with C# and would think writing a class library would be the least overhead for automation.  Here are some potential solutions:

1. **Scripting Library (e.g., C#.NET)** - You can use a library like the one you mentioned or something like [ScriptSharp](https://github.com/nikhilk/scriptsharp) if you want to use DOM manipulation.  If the HTML has appropriate closing tags you can also use LINQ to easily navigate the HTML (or something like the HTML Agility Pack found on CodePlex). I would even recommend using Mustache with an HTML file template in C#.
2. **JavaScript Library** - If you wanted to stay in pure JavaScript you can use Node.js.  There are file manipulation libraries you can use.
3. **Headless Browsers** - Haven't thought through being able to save the resulting HTML automatically but you can use something like [jsTestDriver](http://code.google.com/p/js-test-driver/) or [Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/)

You can go with the plugins in editors as well, but I would stick with a Java, C#, python, etc. library that you can potentially call from existing application or schedule as a job/service.

Comment: As noted by asgoth - you can use Headless Browsers with Node.js (combination of #2 and #3) to produce the HTML files.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the most complete answer. Based on the different comments, I'll go for the C# approach.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/). It is a headless WebKit which can be executed from te commandline. It accepts a [javascript or coffeescript file](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Examples) as a an argument, which can be used to e.g. do something with a web page. Here is an example:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
   page.open('http://m.bing.com', function(status) {
      var title = page.evaluate(function(s) {
         return document.querySelector(s).innerText;
      }, 'title');
      console.log(title);
      phantom.exit();
   });
```